# How can I parallelize Tensorflow's map_fn in GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow

can't post the code in question, but I'll do my best to describe my scenario.

I have a custom tensorflow operation that I defined using Tensorflow's Autograph. It contains a lot of tensorflow control flow operations automatically converted by autograph. I run this operation on a lot of batches and realized it runs really slow on the GPU because it's not being parallelized through map_fn, yet on the CPU it runs really fast and is being parallelized. I verified CPU is being parallelized and GPU is not by sticking a tf.Print and the beginning and end of the operation, if there is only one operation running at a time the "Start" and "End" would show up in order, otherwise they wouldn't.

In summary, any ideas why my operation would be automatically parallelized on CPU, but not on GPU considering the fact that it has a lot of control flow operations? I've also already tried manually setting the "parallel_iterations" parameter of map_fn.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler "decided" that it was not worth the overhead on a GPU.